# How to define array type for multiple or nested json data from REST API

Tags: rest, graphql, express-graphql

I'm new to GraphQL thingy. I have a problem in fetching array data from API using express-graphql server and I find to hard the solution somewhere. Here is the scenario.

I have a GET data from REST API which has the response that similar like this :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "billy",
    "foods": [
        {
            "food":{
                "name":"crepes",
                "taste": "crunchy"
            }
        },
        {
            "food":{
                "name":"noodle",
                "taste":"spicy"
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

In my schema, I have successfully gets the `id` and `name` which I implement like this :

```
const FoodsType= new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'foods',
  fields: () => ({
    id:{ type: GraphQLInt },
    name:{ type: GraphQLString},
    foods: { type: GraphQLArray}
  })
});
```

As you can see I with my code above, I failed fetching foods data which contains array data because there is no scalar type like `GraphQLArray`.
My question is how do we get the `foods` data with containing multiple json data `food` inside it ?

Comment: `foods: { type: new GraphQLList(FoodsType) },` ? https://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/

Comment: Then how should we provide multiple `food` object inside `foods` ? How should we define `FoodsType` when `food` also an object type

Comment: in `FoodsType` I try to put this `food: {type: new GraphQLObjectType(FoodDetailType)}` but it gets an error

Comment: why there is an object inside object (inside array), is it required? ... define it graphql way and convert data at resolver instead of just forward?

Comment: Because those data is the result from an API and I need to fetch those fields directly without calling new API.

Comment: what is 'direct' when you're using express ??? ... direct can be using 'REST Link' ... then you need a type for each of response depth level ... or define it your way converting REST response to your needs before returning

Comment: @xadm Thank you for your answer and the insight. I finally manage to solve this by define the types for each depth level and only call one resolver.

Comment: post a solution/answer to your own question (with resolver) ... you need only one resolver for converting, too ... if your resolver returns all/whole structure server is asked for, then no need for deeper resolvers

Answer (score 0):

```
const ResType= new GraphQLObjectType({
   name: 'response',
   field:() => ({
       name: {type: GraphQLString}, 
       taste: {type: GraphQLString}
   })
   
});


const FoodsType= new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'foods',
  fields: () => ({
    id:{ type: GraphQLInt },
    name:{ type: GraphQLString},
    foods: { type: new GraphQLList(ResType)}
  })
});
```

Comment: currently I have this FoodsType

`const FoodsType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'foods',
    fields: () => ({
      name: { type: GraphQLString },
      taste: { type: GraphQLString }
    })
  });`

but it looks like adding `foods: {type: FoodsType[]}` makes a syntax error.

Comment: Oh I see, I have modified the answer after checking the example here. Syntax error may be the parsing engine itself doesn't recognise ```[]```.


https://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqlobjecttype

Comment: Thank you for modyfing my code. But still it looks like this `foods: { type: Array<ResType>}` also providing syntax error in my case.

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'

Comment: the error line number is pointing at where  ```foods: { type: Array<ResType>}```  locate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228511/discussion-between-tsecheukfung01-and-billy).

Comment: Yes it is I think there's something wrong in wrapping that ResType

Comment: Array is not a graphql type

Comment: I have check the usage from here. Some examples use ```Array``` as well. We need to pre-define it ?

https://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqlobjecttype

Comment: only form implementation/js purpose, never for `type`, not on index/type lists ... graphql list type is for that

Comment: @xadm If I have made a ```ResType``` as ```GraphQLObjectType```, is it make sense to use it as ```new GraphQLList(ResType)```?

Answer (score 0):

After some attempt, I finally manage to solve this by define the types of every depth level. Here is my answer for schema file.

```
  const FoodsType = new GraphQLObjectType({ 
    name: 'foods',
    fields: () => ({
      id:{ type: GraphQLInt },
      name: { type: GraphQLString },
      foods:{ type: new GraphQLList(FoodType) }
    })
  });
  
  const FoodType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'food',
    fields: () => ({
      food: {type: FoodDetail}
    })
  });
  
  const FoodDetail = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'fooddetail',
    fields: () => ({
      name:{ type: GraphQLString },
      taste:{ type: GraphQLString}
    })
  });
```

And here is the resolver that I get from API

```
  const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
      foods: {
        type: FoodsType,
        args: {
          id: { type: GraphQLInt }
        },
        resolve(parent, args) {
          return axios
            .get(`https://hereisanapi/${args.id}`)
            .then(res => {
              return res.data;
            });
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Then in GraphQL Query I put this.

```
{
  foods(id:1){
    food{
      name,
      taste
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ... and you can easily remove middle type ... `return { id: res.data.id, name: res.data.name, foods: [...res.data.foods.map(item=>item.food)] }` (to see array/structure) ... or even directly `foods: res.data.foods.map(item=>item.food)`

Comment: definitely easier approach!. Thank you @xadm 